How to load composer projects when using TestSuite.setRunTestInSeparateProcess
I am running a phpunit project which uses setRunTestInSeparateProcess in the __construct method and it is causing an error which suggests autoloading of composer isn't being done. See below.
<?php 
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function __construct($name = NULL, array $data = array(), $dataName = '')
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
        
        $this->setRunTestInSeparateProcess(true);
    }

    public function testValidWriteRequest()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, 1);
        
    }
    
}

?>

The error given is:
[root@localhost kitchen-sink.youds.com]# php phpunit-run-tests.php
PHPUnit 9.6.19 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.0.29
Configuration: /usr/local/apache/htdocs/kitchen-sink.youds.com/phpunit.xml

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.099, Memory: 6.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) ExampleTest::testValidWriteRequest with data set "abc" (123, 345)
PHPUnit\Framework\Exception: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader" not found in Standard input code:349
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in Standard input code on line 349
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader" not found in Standard input code:349
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in Standard input code on line 349

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.


Kudos to anyone who knows how to pass autoload to the process which it creates?
I expect the class to have access to PHPUnit\TextUI\XmlConfiguration\Loader but it doesn't when the setRunTestInSeparateProcess method is present.
